# Only IE 11 losing focus on ajax call sometimes ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, internet-explorer-11

I am using a boostrap dialog box to pull in a list with a quantity. After I submit my form, and open the dialog box to check to see if the quantity has updated, it seems to be stale data. I have a call with ajax to the controller and then back to the database to pull in updated info. But when I set a breakpoint in the controller (on server side) it never hits. IT ONLY kicks out of the issue when I set a breakpoint to the function calling ajax within developer tools and debugger. I don't see any console errors either.

I don't have an issue with Firefox, just IE11.. here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function LocationModal() {

        $("#GetLocBtn").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        var partNumber = $("#PartNum").val();
        var Condition = 'Z';
        var urlQry;
        var receiveIsChecked = document.getElementById('Receive').checked;

        var src = 'removed for security';
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: src,
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: { partNumber: partNumber, CCODE: Condition },
            beforeSend: function () {
            },
            success: function (data) {                     
              $("#LocationModalContainer").html(data.LocationModal);
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            }
        });
    };
```

Comment: did you put debugger; inside success funcion to see if that is being triggered?

Comment: @JoséQuintoZamora It's intermittent too. When I get the issue it has the issue until I put a break-point in the calling function, and yes success function then it seems to pull itself back and make the call, and work fine.

Comment: try to remove the beforesend function, as it is empty

Comment: well now I have to get it to have the issue as it's not doing it currently -_-   I will try that but I have other ajax calls with empty beforesends with no issues. You think, async: false, will help?

Comment: I don´t think so, as Ajax call should be async 99% of scenarios to have great user exp...

Comment: maybe it's caching.. I will try cache: false,  and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: hmm looks like the cache:false worked.. I will follow up tomorrow if I don't get that problem anymore. Weird that it's only that area having the problem (that I know of).. now I am going to have to make sure no other areas are being conveniently cached with stale data from IE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is indeed that IE caches the results of Ajax calls. You can prevent that behavior either by adding `cache: false` to every call, like you've discovered, or setting it globally via `ajaxSetup` before you make any calls.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    cache: false
});
```

The use of ajaxSetup is discouraged in the [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/), but might be a good solution for you if you don't use any plugins that might rely on the normal behavior and want to quickly make sure none of your own ajax calls is cached.

Personally, I have my doubts about how real the interference risk mentioned in the documentation is when it comes to the cache setting, since basically you just make IE behave like other browsers.

Comment: Excellent!  If I do need to use ajaxSetup that will save me a bunch of time. Do the other browser not use ajax caching (Firefox specifically)? Also, besides the obvious are there any real disadvantages to turning off ajax caching? Most of (if not all) my calls to ajax are not very time consuming at all. And I would prefer the most up to date data anyway.

Comment: I've only seen it in IE. This article also seems to suggests that IE is special and explains what actually happens: https://blog.httpwatch.com/2009/08/07/ajax-caching-two-important-facts/. As to disadvantages, I guess it depends on your use cases. If you don't see any in your site, go for it. In the end, it's a matter of weighing freshness of data versus minimizing network traffic. If e.g. you know that some data only updates daily, you might decide to cache it.

Comment: Interesting read. Per the article it seems to only cache on Get requests and never for a post. I noticed other side effects of this caching so I am going to turn it off.I think what I will do is use your global method, and when I need to cache specifically, I imagine I can set inline with that specific ajax call to cache: true... while the other will default to false. Thanks for your help!